# SiteMap Not Hiding elements

Tags: asp.net

I have inherited a site which makes extensive use of sitemaps. I have been asked if I can make menu items only appear if the user is logged in at the correct role.

(I know my roles based login is all working correctly)

I have the following in my sitemap

```
 <siteMapNode url="~/" title="Home" description="Home">
<siteMapNode title="Home" url="default.aspx" />
<!--Sets up Product page-->    
    ... Product map always shows, so skipped ...

<siteMapNode title="Support" url="~/support/default.aspx">
  <siteMapNode title="CurrentIssues" url="~/support/Issues.aspx" role="Customer" />
</siteMapNode>
...
```

and this line in my config

```
<add name="main_siteMap" description="Menu Site map Provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" secuirityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
```

Yet no matter whether I am logged in or out, the CurrentIssues Menu option is always visible. (Though if you try to click on it, it takes you to the LoginPage.)

So what have I missed to be able to hide menu items for those that are not logged into the correct role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with what you posted.

The `siteMapNode` value should be `roles` not `role`.

Your `web.config` entry has a typo (`secuirityTrimmingEnabled` has an extra `i`) and should likely more look like this:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="main_siteMap" enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <add name="main_siteMap"
            description="Menu Site map Provider"
            type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider "
            siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
            securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
    </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Also note, that securing the sitemap this way requires the proper implementation of [RoleManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.ASPX), meaning that in this case, you'll also need to secure that path in the web.config:

```
<location path="support/issues.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Customer" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Also note that per [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.ASPX):

> Site-map files with more than 150 nodes can take substantially longer
>   to perform security-trimming operations.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed the typos in code, I can't seem to edit the above). It still doesnt want to hide menu options though..

Comment: Are you using a custom role provider?

Comment: No, its all out of the box stuff. There are multiple sitemaps though, if that has a bearing. I have set all the providers in the config file to use secuirty trimming, and have set Roles where appropriate against menu items. Still no joy. Starting to wonder if I need to do this in code, not configuration :-/

Comment: any help is appreciated. What I need to do is limit certain menu items. (i.e. Allow them to see some support items, but not others unless they log in.).
Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @Matt updated answer. You'll need to have the location path secured in web.config as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to add in the directory of resources a configuration file web.config, where specified roles for each resource that should be allowed to access it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="Manual_de_rol_aprobador.pdf">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="aprobador, administradorDeSistema" />
        <deny users="*" /><!-- Usuarios autenticados -->
        <deny users="?" /><!-- Usuarios anonimos -->
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Manual_de_rol_calificador.pdf">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="calificador, administradorDeSistema" />
        <deny users="*" /><!-- Usuarios autenticados -->
        <deny users="?" /><!-- Usuarios anonimos -->
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>


  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="calificador, aprobador, administradorDeSistema" />
      <deny users="*" /><!-- Usuarios autenticados -->
      <deny users="?" /><!-- Usuarios anonimos -->
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```